# saving xlsx as xls without compability check with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to save some xlsx files as xls file because our SAS 9.2 cannot read xlsx.

When I save in my powershell script I get this message

[image]

I am using this code:

```
function convert_xlst_to_xls([string]$File) {
    $Filepath = Get-Item -Path $File
    Write-Host $Filepath
    $NewFilepath = Join-Path -Path $FilePath.directory.FullName -ChildPath "$($Filepath.basename).xls"

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $true #or false
    $workbook.CheckCompatibility = $false
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Filepath.FullName, [Type]::Missing, $true)

    if (Test-Path $NewFilepath) {
        Remove-Item $NewFilepath
    }

    $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,56)
    $Workbook.Close()
    $Excel.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
    Remove-Variable Excel
    return "$NewFilepath"
}

$New_Excel_File = convert_xlst_to_xls("$filePath")
```

It will not accept the checkcompalility property on workbook.

My console:

```
The property 'CheckCompatibility' cannot be found on this object. Verify 
that the property exists and can be set.
At S:\UO4\DWH\SIJ\CONVERT-EXCEL BACKGRUND3.ps1:32 char:1
+ $workbook.CheckCompatibility = $false
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Is there anyway to force the saveas to save without showing this compabilitycontrol.

Comment: Try $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you , please place an answer

Comment: Note if you have SAS 9.2 running then you are paying SAS license fees.  Why not just install latest version of SAS?